# Google map v2 api: how to show a specific map area

Tags: dictionary, area

I am using google map api v2. I'd like to show a specific map area based on map bound (northeast and southwest coordinates). However, google map api v2 only supports setCenter() method. Is there any formula to calculate center position based on map area?

Answer (score 0):

Use the map's `GetBounds()` method from which you can get the center along with other information.